# Find lat and long from a CSV using python / reges

Tags: python, regex

I have a CSV with rows of addresses. I want to extract the lat and long and insert them into new columns called lat and long.

Address:

```
['900 OLD VIRGINIA BEACH RD\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23451\n(36.848522, 
-75.990597)', '600 PHOENIX DR\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23452\n(36.828849, 
-76.069027)', '100 BASSETT AV\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23452\n(36.838597, 
-76.070625)', '1400 NIMMO PW\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23456\n(36.763408, 
-76.021602)', '600 BUSHNELL CT\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23451\n(36.823212,
 -75.977462)', '4900 SWORD RD\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23459\n(36.90665, 
-76.141786)', '1500 PENROSE AR\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23453\n(36.799177, 
-76.124827)', '2000 INDEPENDENCE BL S\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23453', '4400 
LEAMORE SQUARE RD\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23462\n(36.809335, -76.121166)', '4800 
VIRGINIA BEACH BL\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23462\n(36.843743, -76.142357)']
```

Currently reading up geopandas module in python

Comment: Python comes with a CSV reading library. Use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

-- Split by new line,

-- take the last item in split

-- remove first and last chat

-- split by komma.

```
sa = [ x.split('\n')[-1][1:-1].split(',') for x in arr]

print(sa)
[['36.848522', ' -75.990597'], ['36.828849', ' -76.069027'], ['36.838597', ' -76.070625'],
```

with one wring formatted ['IRGINIA BEACH', ' VA 2345']

Answer (score 0):

This expression,

```
[\s\S]*\(\s*([^,]*?)\s*,([^,]*?)\s*\)
```

might work and probably you might want to add some `if` for those inputs without latitude and longitude.

#### Test

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['900 OLD VIRGINIA BEACH RD\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23451\n(36.848522, -75.990597)', '600 PHOENIX DR\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23452\n(36.828849, -76.069027)', '100 BASSETT AV\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23452\n(36.838597, -76.070625)', '1400 NIMMO PW\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23456\n(36.763408, -76.021602)', '600 BUSHNELL CT\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23451\n(36.823212, -75.977462)', '4900 SWORD RD\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23459\n(36.90665, -76.141786)', '1500 PENROSE AR\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23453\n(36.799177, -76.124827)', '2000 INDEPENDENCE BL S\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23453', '4400 LEAMORE SQUARE RD\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23462\n(36.809335, -76.121166)', '4800 VIRGINIA BEACH BL\nVIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23462\n(36.843743, -76.142357)']

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["lat"]=df[0].str.replace(r'[\s\S]*\(\s*([^,]*?)\s*,([^,]*?)\s*\)', r'\1',regex=True)
df["lon"]=df[0].str.replace(r'[\s\S]*\(\s*([^,]*?)\s*,([^,]*?)\s*\)', r'\2',regex=True)
print(df)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/72uyjB/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/72uyjB/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.